# Ordering of testNG groups

Tags: testng

We are running tests with TestNG; tests are assigned into groups, eg.:

- `SetupGroup`

  - `SetupTest1`
  - `SetupTest2`
- `MainTestGroup`

  - `MainTest1`
  - `MainTest2`

I would like to order groups/test, so my test would run:

1. First: tests located in `SetupGroup`, but in random order
2. Second: tests located in `MainTestGroup`, but also, in random order

Maybe the best would be if it could be configured through testng.xml - but I'm also interested if it is possible using annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it in xml. I am not sure to do it through annotation and don't think its the right way either

```
<suite name="TmpSuite" >

<test name="setup">
  <groups>
    <run>

      <include name="SetupGroup"  />
    </run>
  </groups>
</test>
<test name="Actualrun">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="MainTestGroup"  />
    </run>
  </groups>
</test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2):

Through the xml - [ref](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)

```
<test name="My suite">
  <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
      <group name="z" depends-on="c" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
</test>
```

Through annotations, you would have to mark each method falling in group MainTestGroup to dependsOnGroups on Setupgroup.  Read [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations)

Inside a group, the order is random only and cannot be gauranteed unless until you set dependsonmethods or priority.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too; Shamik was a bit faster, and both solutions work perfectly :-)